# Oracle SQL conditional join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select
    DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID,
    (case
        when DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE is not null
        then DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE
        else TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE end) CLASSIFICATION_CODE,
    CLASSIFICATION.NAME CLASSIFICATION_NAME
from
    DOCUMENT,
    TEMPLATE,
    CLASSIFICATION
where
    DOCUMENT.TEMPLATE_ID = TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_ID and
    DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE = CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATION_CODE(+)
```

What I would like to do is along the lines of:

```
if DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN 
  DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE = CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATION_CODE(+),
ELSE
  TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE = CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATION_CODE(+)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Who can remember what `(+)` means on a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: UGH! Non-ANSI outer join syntax? In 2016!?!?! What is this world coming to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NVL](http://www.oradev.com/nvl.html) or the more standard [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) for that:

```
COALESCE(DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE)
      = CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATION_CODE(+)
```

In ANSI syntax:

```
select
    DOCUMENT.DOCUMENT_ID,
    COALESCE(DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE) 
        CLASSIFICATION_CODE,
    CLASSIFICATION.NAME CLASSIFICATION_NAME
from
    DOCUMENT
inner join 
    TEMPLATE on DOCUMENT.TEMPLATE_ID = TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_ID
left join
    CLASSIFICATION on
         COALESCE(DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE) 
       = CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATION_CODE
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `coalesce` or `nvl`, as other answers have suggested, I'd prefer to join to the `classification` table twice. Yes, the engine has to perform an extra join, but avoiding the functions allows the engine to use an index.

```
SELECT document.document_id,
       COALESCE (d.classification_code, t.classification_code)
          AS classification_code,
       COALESCE (d_c.name, t_c.name) AS classification_name
FROM   document d
       JOIN template t ON d.template_id = t.template_id
       LEFT JOIN classification d_c
          ON d.classification_code = d_c.classification_code
       LEFT JOIN classification t_c
          ON t.classification_code = t_c.classification_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `NVL( DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE )`
- `COALESCE( DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE )`
- or `CASE WHEN DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN DOCUMENT.CLASSIFICATION_CODE ELSE TEMPLATE.CLASSIFICATION_CODE END` (exactly as you used in the `SELECT` clause)

As the join condition, like this:

```
SELECT d.DOCUMENT_ID,
       NVL( d.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, t.CLASSIFICATION_CODE )
         AS CLASSIFICATION_CODE,
       c.NAME AS CLASSIFICATION_NAME
FROM   DOCUMENT d
       INNER JOIN TEMPLATE t
       ON ( d.TEMPLATE_ID = t.TEMPLATE_ID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASSIFICATION c
       ON ( NVL( d.CLASSIFICATION_CODE, t.CLASSIFICATION_CODE )
              = c.CLASSIFICATION_CODE )
```